# How to create a DetailViewController for UISplitViewController?

Tags: ipad

I have developed a program for iPad programmatically. I have a SplitViewController, RootViewController and DetailViewController.
I am able to get the UITableViewController as a popover.
How to get a UILabel been displayed on DetailViewController on click of each index of the UITableViewController programmatically?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

The template that Apple provides for you in XCode does exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I realise the original poster has probably long since moved on from needing an answer to this question. Since I recently needed to search for a similar question, did not find a suitable question/answer, I decided to start digging for myself, and came up with an answer that may be useful for someone else.

As mentioned by @Wes, the template provided in XCode for "Master-Detail Application" does create useful jumping off point to create a universal app with a view controller:

**XCode 4.2 New Project Dialog**
[image]

**be sure to also choose Universal..**

[image]

What I did find however, which was not inherently obvious, is that whilst when using the app as an iPhone app, you will get a call to method `setDetailItem:` in the detailViewController  (which will in turn call  `configureView`), you won't automatically get this happening in the iPad version of the app. this is because the _detailViewController ivar (mapped to by detailViewController property) in masterViewController is nil by default.

This is because in the iPhone version, when you select a detail item, the default code checks to see if this iVar is nil, and autocreates one for you. in the iPad version however, the `[appDelegate application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]` has already created a single detailViewController for you, along with a masterViewController. to get this working in my code, what I did was add the following lines in the `[appDelegate application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]` method, as follows:

```
    masterViewController.detailViewController = detailViewController;
    
    [masterViewController tableView:masterViewController.tableView 
            didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

The second line automatically selects the first detail item for you on app start. This is safe in the default demo code, because it is set up to handle 1 detail. if you are going to change that in your code (eg by creating the detail items dynamically from some other source) you will of course need to ensure there is a valid detail item there to select at position 0.

The method (after i added these 2 lines) looks like this now:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    } else {
        MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];
        
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController] autorelease];
        
        masterViewController.detailViewController = detailViewController;
        
        [masterViewController tableView:masterViewController.tableView 
                didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
        
        
        self.splitViewController = [[[UISplitViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
        self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController, nil];
        
        self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
    }
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```